# Task from Workflow questions / issue

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a question in regards to the user the system uses when assigning a task from a workflow. I have a workflow on a field in account and if this field reach 90% the workflow fires. This workflow will create a **task** for the account owner of that account that has reached 90% on that specific field.
If I use the "Notify Assignee" on the **Edit Task** section, an email is send to the account owner with a template that it can't be modify. I said it can't after doing a search on this matter. But, what about the user that the system use to send that email notification? 
I thought that I could change that by changing the **Edit Organization-Wide Email Address** in Email Administration, but is not picking that email.

Anyone knows from where the task "Notify Assignee" gets the user to be utilizes on the task's email notification template? 
This user also shows up in the new Task as the "Created By". Any ideas how can I modify this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the default work flow user or the user who triggered the work flow to fire. Other than changing the default work flow user I don't think you can influence this in work flow rules.

The organisation wide email addresses are for allowing users to send email from a generic email address from within Salesforce e.g.  Sales@address.net rather than their own.